# Web API HttpPost body with spaces and quotes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to create an HttpPost controller method which takes a string which may include spaces or single quotes.  The code I have now looks like:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("ValidateExpression")]
public bool ValidateExpression([FromBody] string testExpression )
{
    // ...
}
```

and I post to it via JS (Angular) like:

```
$http.post(myRootUrl +'ValidateExpression', "'token1' || 'token2'");
```

I can walk through the JS and see that the test expression is what I expect it to be, and it also looks fine in the body of the outgoing post (as seen in Fiddler & Firebug).  But when I breakpoint in the first line of ValidateExpression on the server side, `testExpression` has been truncated to the first space, and stripped of quotes, so what I receive is `token1`.

How can I avoid this unwanted transformation?

I guess that I could create a model to wrap a single string, and send my string as field value in a JSON object matching the model...or I could do some escaping on the string, but the first seems ugly/unnecessary and the second seems like I'd be trying to hack around behaviour I don't really understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass in JSON object with key equal to that of parameter name.

```
// POST api/values
public string Post(string value) {
  return value;
}

$.post('/api/values', { value: 'Dave' });
```

Alternatively, you can satisfy Web API's encoding requirement these ways:

```
$.post('api/values', "=" + value);
```

or

```
$.post('api/values', { '': value });
```

More information here: http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-post-frombody-parameters-to-web-api/

Edit:

Also, note that angualrjs http.post and jquery.post behaves differently:

> The difference is in how jQuery and AngularJS serialize and transmit
>   the data. Fundamentally, the problem lies with your server language of
>   choice being unable to understand AngularJS’s transmission
>   natively—that’s a darn shame because AngularJS is certainly not doing
>   anything wrong. By default, jQuery transmits data using Content-Type:
>   x-www-form-urlencoded and the familiar foo=bar&baz=moe serialization.
>   AngularJS, however, transmits data using Content-Type:
>   application/json and { "foo": "bar", "baz": "moe" } JSON
>   serialization, which unfortunately some Web server languages—notably
>   PHP—do not unserialize natively.
>
> http://victorblog.com/2012/12/20/make-angularjs-http-service-behave-like-jquery-ajax/